# Regex to match digits within braces

Tags: python, regex, file

I have problem in extraction of certain data in the following program where it has been marked with bold and italics. I want to extract those data from a file and process it as follows.

```
i 1CAT(0)

i 2CAT(1)

o 22CAT(10)

o 23CAT(9)

g1 ***and*** 6CAT(**3**) 3CAT(**2**) ; 11CAT(**5**)

g2 ***or*** 3CAT(**2**) 1CAT(**0**) ; 10CAT(**16**)
```

Example:

line 5: if(and) appears then do 3+2*5

line 6: if(or) appears then do 2-0+16

etc....

Code till now:

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/pr/Documents/')
inputFile=open('C17.txt','r')
inputfile.readline()
print inputFile.read()
inputFile.close()
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: yes it is . i am learning python regex...regex till now : re.findall(r'(0-9)',inputFile). the problem here is it can match those within braces, but I need to extract those separate matches and process it..

Comment: If a question is homework, please make sure you tag the question as homework.  This allows people to help you without doing your assignment for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between braces you want to match in the string and braces that belongs to your regular expression.

All kind of braces have a special meaning for a regular expression, so if you want to match them, you need to escape them.

**Regarding your regex from your comment**

> re.findall(r'(0-9)',inputFile)

- `re.findall` [(link)](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall), needs a string as second argument and not a file handle.
- `(0-9)` is just matching **one** digit and because the brackets aren't escaped the value is stored in a  capturing group. [(Check here the paragraph `(...)`)](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). If you want to match numbers with more than one digit at once, you should have a look into quantifiers (`+`,`*`,`{m,n}` same link than before).

**Regarding your code in the OP**

You are aware that the code you presented has not much to do with the task (except the file opening and closing). You may want to have a look at the Python tutorial about ["Reading and Writing Files"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: I managed to read the file as string using this regex d=re.findall(r'\([0-9]\)',s). This is stored in d[0,1,..i]How can I read it line by line and get the operation done for 'and' , 'or' ?

Comment: @RPK ???????? ? You can't read a file as string with a regex. You could read a file line by line (as string) or all at once into a list of lines(strings) or a certain amount of bytes(as strings). I think you should read it all at once and loop over the list. See the link I gave you, its very simple. And inside the loop you can do some thing with each line string.

Comment: g1 and 6CAT(3) 3CAT(2) ; 11CAT(15)
I want to insert 'and' logic to get the number between braces.till now i used d=re.findall(r'\([0-9]\)',s). I am getting (3) , (2) but not (15). how to extract double digit number between braces.

Comment: @RPK have you read my answer? And the result of your regex is `['1', '6', '3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '5']`, I think thats not what you want. Solution: 1. Read my answer 2. Escape brackets that you want to match 3. Use quantifiers to match more than once